# How can I improve the routing in S2?

Tags: php, symfony

I would want to set a special pattern in a route into routing.yml.
For example, in this case:

```
search_result:
     pattern:    /results/{ubication}/{page}
     defaults:   
         _controller: SiteBundle:Web:searchResult
         ubication:   'Madrid'
         page:        1
```

I would like that the routing matches the following paths:

```
/results
/results/
/results/Madrid
/results/Madrid/
/results/Madrid/2
```

What is the best way to do?
Create multiples routings for each case is not an option

Comment: See: [How to allow a "/" character in a route parameter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with annotation :

```
@Route("/results/")
@Route("/results/{ubication}/")
@Route("/results/{ubication}/{page}")
```

Set it in the comments of your php method and you should be able to call the url you want